# Cross domain ajax in a multisite setup

Tags: ajax, multi-sites

I have a drupal multisite install so that two sites can share the same codebase. In a custom module that both sites use, the ajax works on one site but with the other site it returns the error status 200. What my module does is that it creates a new "article" node programmatically.

I read somewhere that this is a crossdomain ajax problem, even though both sites are really on the same hard drive of the same server.

The views module, which also uses ajax, works on both sites with no problem.

How can I make the ajax work? I'll give up the multisite way if it creates more problems than it solves

Update: here is the jquery code :

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.addArticle = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {                              
            var addstuffAjaxLink = $(".addsomething");          
            addstuffAjaxLink.click(function(e) {                            
                var ajaxpath = 'addstuff/ajax';         
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: ajaxpath,
                    data: {'from_js': true},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {              
                        if (data.message) {                             
                            var message= data.message;                      
                            alert(message);                             
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xmlhttp) {
                        alert('An error occured: ' + xmlhttp.status);                       
                    }
                });         
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and this is the custom module php code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function addstuff_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['addstuff/ajax'] = array(
   'title' => 'Add Stuff',
    'page callback' => 'addstuff_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
/**
 * Menu callback.
 */
function addstuff_callback() {
    if ($_POST['from_js']) {
        global $user;

        $newnode = new stdClass();
        $newnode->uid = $user->uid;
        $newnode->name = $user->name;   
        $newnode->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
        $lan=$newnode->language;
        $newnode->status = 1;     
        $newnode->promote = 0;
        $newnode->sticky = 0;
        $newnode->created = timestamp;                      
        $newnode->title = 'New Article';
        $newnode->type = 'article';

        $newnode->field_body = array(
            $lan => array(
                array(
                    'value' => 'Click HERE to add some text.',
                    'format'=> 'full_html',
                    'safe_value' => 'Click HERE to add some text.',
                )
            )
        );
        node_save($newnode);            
        $response = array(
            'message' => 'Article Created',
        );
        return drupal_json_output($response);
        exit;           
    } else {
        $response = array(
            'message' => 'There was an error',
        );
        drupal_json_output($response);
        exit;
    }
}
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function addstuff_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'addstuff') . '/addstuff.js');
}
```

Comment: I guess, you are using jquery for you ajax calls. If yes, than check your dataType. It should be "jsonp"

Comment: check these urls. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133864/ajax-cross-domain-problem

Comment: I'm afraid we would need more information. Possibly, the code snippet that you are trying to get to work and the context it is being run from and what "works from the other site" actually means.

From what I understand, I doubt if it has anything to do with the multi-site setup and cross-domain in its simplest form, means "accessing data of a host from a client on a different host" - it doesn't depend on *where* your site is being served from, actually.

Comment: I added the code. I'll try to give more details : on domain1.com and on domain2.com there is a button with the class "addsomething". When the user clicks on that button, it runs the jquery code, which in turns fires the php code, to add an article node. Clicking on the button on domain1.com should add the node in the database of domain1, whereas clicking on the similar button on domain2.com should create the node in domain2's database, but instead it gives an xmlhttp error 200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd probably do is to change the `url` option of `$.ajax` to something like:

```
$.ajax({
  // your code goes here
  url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'addstuff/ajax',
  // more of your code goes here
});
```

So, what could be happening (assuming of course, that you have clean URLs enabled on both sites) is that when you are on a page on your site with the Drupal path, say, `node/add` and click on your link, the AJAX request to `addstuff/ajax` without the leading slash (base path) goes to `node/addaddstuff/ajax` which will return HTML and not JSON as expected. Hence, jQuery throws a `parseerror` and Drupal calls its error handler. You can check this by inspecting the XHR requests being sent out from the *Network* tab of your browser's developer console.

However, this doesn't explain how your code works as expected on one site but not the other.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll give it a shot